# Tail call optimization for void return typed function

Tags: optimization, recursion

Will Tail call optimization work for recursive calls to a function that returns void? For example I have a function, **void fun()**

```
void fun()
{
    ...
    ...
    ...
    fun();
}
```

Here the compiler will not know that, calling fun() is the last statement. So is tail call optimization done only for functions that return some value?

Comment: Depends on the compiler. Which one are you using?

Comment: @RogerLipscombe GCC. But whichever compiler I use, how will the compiler know that it is the last statement? There is no explicit return as in the case of a function that returns some value, say returing int..

Comment: I'm wondering, what difference would the return type make? My guess is tail optimization will work in this case

Comment: The compiler can deduce that it's the last statement from the fact that it is immediately followed by the closing brace.

Comment: @shar if there is no explicit return, when will the recursion end?

Comment: @Arjun Maybe there is a conditional `return;` somewhere before.

Comment: @DanielFischer That makes sense and I could visualize that now.. Thanks:)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is that yes, it can, but the compiler is under no obligation to do so.  Whether it does or not depends a lot on the function, the compiler, and the selected optimization level.  If you're concerned about this for a particular function, look at the assembly produced by a specific compiler at a specific optimization level.

To be more specific, GCC (at least the Apple version that uses LLVM as a backend) will produce tail-call optimized code for at least some functions returning `void` at optimization level `-O1` or better.

Some test code:

```
/* Fills an array with a single value, recursively with side effects */
void fillarray(int val, int* curr, int* end)
{
  if (curr==end) return;

  *curr = val;
  fillarray(val,curr+1,end);
}
```

With minimal optimization (`-O1`), compiling to assembly (`gcc -O1 -S test.c`) produces a nicely tail-call optimized function:

```
_fillarray:
        pushq       %rbp
        movq        %rsp, %rbp   # set up the stack

        cmpq        %rdx, %rsi   # early exit if beg == end
        je  LBB1_2
LBB1_1:
        movl        %edi, (%rsi) # *curr = val
        addq        $4, %rsi     # curr++

        cmpq        %rsi, %rdx   # TAIL CALL optimization is here
        jne LBB1_1               # if curr != end, go to LBB1_1
LBB1_2:
        popq        %rbp         # restore the stack and exit
        ret
```

(Note: I've edited out some of the unnecessary labels and alignment statements which obscure the structure of the assembly).

Also, when optimization is turned off (`-O0`), the code produced is recursive (not tail-call optimized).